# text-to-speech API with translations

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech, translate

I'm an iPhone developer, and i need an API where to send text and language as arguments, and it has to return the speech of the text. Kind of text-to-speech, but with translation also. I searched over the internet, but cannot find one. Does anybody know any API like this? 
Thanks.

eg: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=this%20is%20not%20good

something like this, but if i change tl=it, it has to speech directly in italian.
thanks a lot.